# How get data from double Map (Angular - Spring)

Tags: angular, typescript, hashmap

I get double hashmap from spring and put it in variable pr. In theory the variable pr already has the correct format but it cannot get the information through the keys. Any help plz?

```js
getData(): Observable<Map<number, Map<string, boolean>>> {
  const endpointUrl = this.apiUri + '/info';
  return this.http.get<Map<number, Map<string, boolean>>>(endpointUrl);
}

getAll() {
  this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    let pr = data;
    console.log(pr.get(1).get('A'));
  });
}
```

The console returns ERROR TypeError: pr.get is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting the response/result from the backend correctly?

Comment: I have an error but the  Map structure should be correct Observable<Map<number, Map<string, boolean>>>

Comment: Could you please log the `data` before calling the `pr.get(1)`?

Comment: no, i need use the two keys to find the value , the question is why is not showing the first key.

Answer (score 0):

1: { 134: {A: true, B: true, C: true, …}}

With your data provide the data type should be updated as below :

```js
Map<number, Map<string, Map<string, boolean>>>
```

Comment: What is data from API could you give me partial data? @DavidRod

Comment: finally the data is displayed correctly but the variable keeps giving the same error The console returns ERROR TypeError: pr.get is not a function.

Comment: How about with this (data as Map<number, Map<string, boolean>>).get(1).get('A') @DavidRod

Comment: The problem is this https://javascript.tutorialink.com/map-get-is-not-a-function-while-retrieving-a-value-from-a-map-in-typescript/